# UseEffect hook does not work or how to display async data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning react and making a project that has a component that needs to display async information:

```
function ShortStatistic() {

    const [coronaData, setCoronaData] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const fetchedPosts = await getCoronaData();
            setCoronaData(fetchedPosts);
        })();
        console.log("UseEffectCall");
    }, []);

    async function getCoronaData() {
        const URL = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary";
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            redirect: 'follow'
        };
      
        const response = await fetch(URL, requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }


    return (
        <div className="stat">
             <div className="stat_infected">
                  Infected:
                    <span className="infected_numbers">
                         {(coronaData["Global"]["TotalConfirmed"])}
                    </span>
              </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But I am getting an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'TotalConfirmed' of undefined", what means setCoronaData() didn't work. Also, there is no message output from the useEffect hook (console.log("UseEffectCall");) in the console. What is the problem?

Comment: `useEffect` is called _after_ the initial render, so during the initial render, `coronaData["Global"]` is undefined. As a result, `coronaData["Global"]["TotalConfirmed"]` causes an error because its like doing: `undefined["TotalConfirmed"]`. You need to check if `coronaData["Global"]` is defined before accessing any property on it. Using optional chaining, you can do: `coronaData?.["Global"]?.["TotalConfirmed"]`

Comment: @Yousaf Thanks for the help! Then I'll probably do an initial verification of coronaData or write an initial state-template for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for first render your coronaData variable is an empty array [] and when you call

```
coronaData["Global"]["TotalConfirmed"]
```

it means undefined

You can use

```
coronaData?.["Global"]?.["TotalConfirmed"]
```